Custom structure for multi-step webform's submission
I need to send webform submission data in an email with a specific structure:
<h2>Wizard Page 1 Title</h2>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>Element Title</td>
        <td>Submission Value</td>
      </tr>
      ...
</table>
<h2>Wizard Page 2 Title</h2>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td>Element Title</td>
        <td>Submission Value</td>
      </tr>
      ...
</table>

I'm using the twig option in an email handler. I tried to loop through {{data}} in the handler's twig template, but it doesn't have wizard elements available.
I need to do that for one specific webform
Thanks!


I don’t understand what this post is asking.

@monalisa I'm asking for help with using tokens in the webform submission email. I've updated the post a little bit, hope it's clearer now.
As {{data}} token doesn't contain wizard page elements, is there a token that does and has a structure that I can use to present the info like it is with the default submission template, but showing elements values as a table?

Answering my own question, wizard pages are in the loop of elements_flattened:
   {% for key, value in elements_flattened %}
  {% if value['#type'] == 'webform_wizard_page' %}
    {% if  (loop.first == false) %}
      </table>
    {% endif %}
<h2>{{ value['#title'] }}</h2>
<table>
  {% else %}
    {% if ((webform_token('[webform_submission:values:' ~ key ~ ':clear]', webform_submission)) and (value['#type'] != 'webform_markup') and (value['#type'] != 'webform_message') ) %}
      {% if value['#type'] == 'container' or value['#type'] == 'fieldset' %}
      {% if value['#title'] %}<tr><th colspan="2">{{ value['#title'] }}</th></tr>{% endif %}
        {% else %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ value['#title']|striptags }}</td>
        <td>{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:' ~ key ~ ']', webform_submission) }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>

